# What is that "it" represents in Psalm 91:7?

Tags: psalms

New International Version Psalm 91:7

> A thousand may fall at your side, ten thousand **at your right hand**, but **it** will not come **near you**.

*It* cannot literally be death because people are dying right near his right and left. I don't see it as a metaphor either because metaphorically *it* is also close to him whatever *it* is. Is it some kind of spiritual thing?

Answer (score 1):

Ps 91:5-7 (BSB says:

> 5 You will not fear the terror of the night, nor the arrow that flies
> by day,
>
> 6 nor the pestilence that stalks in the darkness, nor the calamity
> that destroys at noon.
>
> 7 Though a thousand may fall at your side, and ten thousand at your
> right hand, no **harm** will come near you.

The word "harm" above is not in the Hebrew but is implied.  The NIV, NASB etc and similar just have "it".  The clear reference to the "harm" (BSB) or "pestilence" (CSB) has its antecedent as:

"terror of the night, nor the arrow that flies by day, nor the pestilence that stalks in the darkness, nor the calamity that destroys at noon."

Note that this includes all threats in a pair of hendiadys - "night and day" plus, "darkness and noon(day)".  Thus, the Psalm is a promise of protection from all harm and threats.